# Execute different functions based on conditions without if statements

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-style

Is there a better approach/coding style to execute different functions under different conditions **without** using if statements?

I have been coding in the following way in JavaScript: (for example, a function in different conditions might use different fetch methods from an API)

```
if(answer == 'a'){
  foo()

if(answer == 'b'){
  bar()

if(answer == 'c'){
  bar_2()

if(answer == 'd'){
  foo_3()
```

I have thought of using `eval()`, but is it a good approach? for example, creating an object consists of keys as conditions and function names as property.

```
conditions:{
  a: 'foo',
  b: 'bar',
  c: 'foo_2',
  d: 'bar_2',
}
```

and run it like `eval(this.conditions[a])`

But I also heard that using `eval` would be difficult for testing.

Comment: Don't store strings with function names and `eval` them. Just store the functions themselves, and call them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can build your conditions object with the function and call them:

```
function foo(){...}
function bar(){...}

var conditions : {
    'a': foo,
    'b': bar,
}

conditions[answer]()
```

Note: try not to use `eval` whenever is possible it has security risks if you don't know what are you doing

Answer (score 1):

You use key to point to a function identifier. You better use key to point to function:

```
conditions:{
  a: () => {
    // body of foo
  },
  b: () => {
    // body of bar
  },
  c: () => {
    // body of foo_2
  },
  d: () => {
    // body of bar_2
  }
}

conditions[ your_key ]();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define reference to a functions or to be executed under each condition

```
const doSomething = (args) => {
    // do something
}
const doSomethingElse = (args) => {
    // do something else
}

const conditions = {
    a: doSomething,
    b: doSomethingElse
};

// and then
const result = conditions[answer](params);
```

or even list of function references

```
const conditions = {
    a: [
        doSomething,
    ],
    b: [
        doSomething,
        doSomethingElse
    ]
};
// and then
const results = conditions[ answer ].map(method => method());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions like this:

```
this['some answer'] = function() {...}
```

And then call it like

```
this[answer]()
```